# SVG image width and height - "px" needed?

Tags: html, svg

Which is correct?

```
<svg width="100px" height="200px">
    ...
</svg>
```

or this

```
<svg width="100" height="200">
    ...
</svg>
```

I know that in case of `<img>` tag we must not specify the `px`, because if I validate against [W3C](https://validator.w3.org/) I receive an error message:

**Bad value 100px for attribute height on element img: Expected a digit but saw p instead.**

**Bad value 200px for attribute width on element img: Expected a digit but saw p instead.**

But this error message is not shown for `<svg>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#Units)

> One px unit is defined to be equal to one user unit. Thus, a length of "5px" is the same as a length of "5".

So you can use either, as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

both of them is true and work ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pixels if you want the SVG to be a fixed height and width but if you want it to follow the scale of the website you can try using percentages that's what I have used in my website atleast